# Fazer um upload em html e salvar no Google drive

Tags: php, html5, google-drive-api

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um formulário com campos de uploads em html e salvar esses arquivos no Google drive.

Li sobre o forms.studio, porém os códigos deles são pagos.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP você consegue manipular os arquivos que o usuário sobe pro servidor usando a função [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Com ela, você move o arquivo para algum lugar do seu servidor e depois usa a [API do Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) para enviar o arquivo.

Então, respondendo sua pergunta, é sim perfeitamente possível.